# How can I manually test a kerberos SPI for tomcat SSO

Tags: spring-security, kerberos

I'm trying to debug my spring-security-kerberos web app that runs on tomcat6 on Centos5.5
and have a service principal in a keytab that i generated on a windows 2008 AD. I would like to test the keys outside of tomcat to help isolate the problem (Spring does not fine the keys)

i can list the keys with the `ktutil` program and see the principal in in the table but cant verify that it actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was flipping through old questions and stumbled across this one.  So you've already listed the keys with kutil.  To verify that the principal inside the Kerberos key table file actually works, you can run this command:  `kinit -k -t <key table file name> <SPN>`.

For instance, if you have an SPN of HTTP/somehost.mydomain.com and a key table file name of myfilename.keytab, your command will be:

`kinit -k -t myfilename.keytab HTTP/somehost.mydomain.com`

This is a simple Kerberos test fully outside of Tomcat (which meets your requirement), and verifies that your DNS, AD, krb5.conf, and keytab (including principle inside) are all set up correctly.

Comment: It's cool to get a good answer to a six year old question, when I was working on this it would have saved a lot of testing time.

Comment: Yes, I'm a new (3 months) user.  I didn't know about this site back then.  There were two reasons why I answered this.  (1) It's fun trolling through old un-answered questions to see if I can grab one I know is solidly in my wheelhouse (this one was).  And (2) I'm was looking at un-answered questions from users with (a) high rep (b/c they tend to respond) AND (b) have been active relatively recently as I don't want to waste my time with someone who probably will never see any notification heads up.  I saw that you were active just a few hours ago so that nailed it for me - I was answering it.